# Mercurial commit fails when text editor pops up

Tags: mercurial, ubuntu-12.04

Fairly new to Mercurial, I want to perform my initial commit of my personal project. I am working locally on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

When I perform the commands:

```
hg init [folder]
cd [folder]
hg add
hg commit
```

At the commit something goes wrong and the commit gets aborted. I notice two abnormal things:

- Mercurial **opens but does not wait for exit** an *empty* gedit window, so when I edit the file hg already aborted the commit because the message is empty;
- gedit pops up with a empty file instead of the usual

  HG: Enter commit message.  Lines beginning with 'HG:' are removed.
  HG: Leave message empty to abort commit.
  ... etc ...

How do I get this working?
Note also that the following command works!

```
hg commit -m 'initial commit'
```

My Mercurial configuration file looks like:

```
# User Interface settings
[ui]
username= Niccolò X <mymail@x.is>
editor = gedit
merge=meld

# Enabled extensions
[extensions]
hgext.gpg=
hgext.convert=

# GPG extension settings
#[gpg]
#key=<your private gpg key>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you'll find that the problem only occurs when you already have an instance of `gedit` open (i.e. pretty much always as that's what you do when you're programming).  When you run `gedit` to edit the commit message, it is telling your currently running `gedit` instance to load the file and then exiting.  The problem with that is that Mercurial assumes that you've done editing the commit message when the editor exits which isn't the case in this instance.

This problem has been discussed on the Mercurial mailing list, [here](http://www.selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2006-October/011354.html), but the thread didn't come up with a solution to the problem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553553/501710) answer implies that setting your editor to `gedit --new-window` might work but I can't test it myself as I don't use Linux.

Comment: Thanks to find where the problem is. The discussion in the mailing list is clear. Unfortunately launching gedit with --new-window does not help because it works in the same way of gedit without options: it calls the existent gedit process and returns before you edit the file :( Apart the aforementioned discussion, this links explains why gedit keeps only one process https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/2008-December/msg00043.html